# MS SQL Query Execution Plan Cache has queries not issued by any application

Tags: sql-server

My Application issues queries i.e.:

```
(@P1 bigint)SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYTABLE_ID = @P1
(@P1 bigint)SELECT * FROM MYTABLE (NOLOCK) WHERE MYTABLE_ID = @P1
```

But in Plan Cache I also see queries like this (note the brackets):

```
(@1 int)SELECT * FROM [MYTABLE] WHERE [MYTABLE_ID]=@1
```

This queries are not issued by any application. Where do they come from? Are they created by MS SQL Simple Parameterization? (Parameterization set to simple)

This queries have refcount > 2 in sys.dm_exec_cached_plans DMV. What does refcount mean? Can someone elaborate?

Comment: Well, it is Parameterization. Someone answered my question with this [http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3834501/Parameterized-Queries.htm](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3834501/Parameterized-Queries.htm) but deleted his/hers answer. But I still don't know what refcount  means?